# Unable to find solution for SMTP connection for Microsoft outlook

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to connect to the SMTP server.

However, I am getting the error below:

> ConnectionRefusedError: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

```
import smtplib

conn = smtplib.SMTP('smtp-mail.outlook.com', 587)
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't really established a connection within your code. Try to do it like this:

```
import smtplib

email=input('Insert email: ')
password=input('Insert password: ')

server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp-mail.outlook.com', 587)
server.ehlo()
server.starttls()
server.ehlo()

server.login(email, password)
```

Make sure the credentials are correct, otherwise it'll raise a 'smtplib.SMTPAuthenticationError'. Once you're done reading/sending/whatever else you have to do, don't forget to add `server.close()` to the script before terminating it.